# Trying to connect to Google Analytics API through AWS Lambda, what does this "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine' " mean

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to connect to use the Google Analytics API through AWS Lambda and then pull in data to put inside of an AWS RDS instance.  I'm able to connect to my DB through Lambda, and the script works fine locally but when trying to run it on Lambda I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'`.

Haven't tried anything to solve this problem.  Google searched the google appengine and its part of an SDK or something.  Wondering what that means in terms of trying to connect to Lambda and how to proceed.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import sys
import csv
from datetime import datetime

import pymysql
import googleapiclient.discovery

from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient import sample_tools
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def handler(event,context):
  main(sys.argv)

def main(argv):
    #Define the auth scopes to request.
    scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
    key_file_location = 'serviceaccount.json'

    #Authenticate and construct service.
    service = get_service(

            api_name='analytics',
            api_version='v3',
            scopes=[scope],
            key_file_location=key_file_location)

    #profile_id = profile_id = '######'
    profile_id = profile_id = '########'
    date, sessions = print_results(get_ga_metrics(service,profile_id))
    write_to_sql(date,sessions)

def get_service(api_name, api_version, scopes, key_file_location):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(key_file_location, scopes=scopes)
    service = build(api_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
    return service

def get_ga_metrics(service, profile_id):
  """Executes and returns data from the Core Reporting API.

  This queries the API for the top 25 organic search terms by visits.

  Args:
    service: The service object built by the Google API Python client library.
    profile_id: String The profile ID from which to retrieve analytics data.

  Returns:
    The response returned from the Core Reporting API.
  """

  return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='30daysAgo',
      end_date = 'yesterday',
      metrics='ga:sessions',
      dimensions='ga:date'
      ).execute()

def print_results(results):
    date =[]
    sessions =[]
    for row in results.get('rows'):
        date.append(row[0])  #loop thru new values in list to convert to datetime 
        sessions.append(row[1])

    #dateformatted =[]  
    #for dates in date:

         #date1 = datetime.strptime(dates,'%Y%m%d')
         #dateformatted.append(date1)
    dates = [datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in date]

    #print(dateformatted,sessions)
    print(dates)
    return dates,sessions

def write_to_sql(date,sessions):
    db=pymysql.connect(host="################",user="###########",
                  passwd="#########",db="############")

    cur = db.cursor()                
    all_list = list(zip(date,sessions))

    sql = "INSERT INTO analytics (`date`,`sessions`) VALUES (%s,%s);"
    cur.executemany(sql,all_list)
    db.commit()
    cur.close()

main(sys.argv)
```

This is what I get when I run the script locally.

```
['2019-04-22', '2019-04-23', '2019-04-24', '2019-04-25', '2019-04-26', '2019-04-27', '2019-04-28', '2019-04-29', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-01', '2019-05-02', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-04', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-06', '2019-05-07', '2019-05-08', '2019-05-09', '2019-05-10', '2019-05-11', '2019-05-12', '2019-05-13', '2019-05-14', '2019-05-15', '2019-05-16', '2019-05-17', '2019-05-18', '2019-05-19', '2019-05-20', '2019-05-21']
```

This is the error that AWS Lambda is throwing at me.

```
START RequestId: 33b53026-5c40-4040-8bba-8d4d58cdc553 Version: $LATEST
[WARNING]   2019-05-22T17:23:32.437Z        file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 36, in autodetect
    from google.appengine.api import memcache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 33, in <module>
    from oauth2client.contrib.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.contrib.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 37, in <module>
    from oauth2client.locked_file import LockedFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client.locked_file'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 41, in autodetect
    from . import file_cache
  File "/var/task/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 41, in <module>
    'file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth')
ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth
END RequestId: 33b53026-5c40-4040-8bba-8d4d58cdc553
REPORT RequestId: 33b53026-5c40-4040-8bba-8d4d58cdc553  Duration: 10011.13 ms   Billed Duration: 10000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 30 MB  
2019-05-22T17:23:39.538Z 33b53026-5c40-4040-8bba-8d4d58cdc553 Task timed out after 10.01 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn off cache discovery when building your service:

```py
service = build(
    api_name,
    api_version,
    credentials=credentials,
    cache_discovery=False,
)
```